# A majority of us are hiding THEIR or OUR feelings?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure which is the correct option in sentences like these ones:

1. Each of us has to learn how to express their/ our feelings.
2. majority of us are hiding their/ our feelings.

"Their" sounds slightly better to me, but still I am confused.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal usage, the determiner (e.g. your, our, their) must match the object pronoun (you, us, them):

> Some of **us** express **our** feelings.
> Half of **them** hate **their** teachers.
> Most of **you** have eaten **your** lunch.

Comment: Well, it doesn't _have_ to. "Most of us are hiding their feelings" would (very strangely, for sure) mean we are hiding the feelings of some other group of people. Odd but completely valid grammar.

Comment: In 1945, after the Allied victory the British (Conservative) government issued a special poster which was alleged by some to have helped them lose the next election to Labour; it had the slogan "Our victory was made possible by your sacrifice".